# Как сделать картинки одного размера в колонке

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть флекс-контейнер, в нем 4 колонки, в каждой колонке по 2 изображения, из-за того, что они разные, колонки становятся разного размера тоже, пробовал через height - не получается, пробовал через html задать высоту картинок - теряются пропорции, что тоже не есть хорошо. Итак, вопрос знатокам: как без потери качества и пропорций привести все картинки и колонки к единой высоте?

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery { display: flex; }

.gallery__col { width: 25%; }

.gallery__img { max-width: 100%; }
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section__header">
      <h3 class="section__title">Галлерея</h3>
      <p class="section__text">Эстетика интерьера и кофе</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery__col">
      <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/400/600">
      <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/600/400">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery__col">
      <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/300">
      <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/700/500">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery__col">
      <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300">
      <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/350/300">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery__col">
      <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/800/500">
      <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/400/400">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Повесить картинки на бекграунд элемента у которого будет задана определенная высота, например

Comment: @Simon да, думал об этом, но я хотел сделать попап, да и в любом случае хотел бы разобраться с этим

Comment: Тогда попробуйте [object-fit](https://html5book.ru/svoystva-object-fit-i-object-position/)

Comment: @humster_spb пробовал, 0 эффекта

Comment: Покажите Ваши пробы, сделайте в сниппете воспроизводимый пример - посмотрим, что не получается

Comment: @humster_spb я дико извиняюсь, но как это сделать? Скриншоты получаются овер 2мб, не получается загрузить даже обрезанные.

Comment: @НикитаГришин вместо картинок можете [сервисом](https://placeholder.com/) воспользоваться.

Comment: _«в сниппете воспроизводимый пример - как это сделать?»_ - в редактировании вoпроса нажать `Ctrl` + `M` (латинская) и в открывшемся "окне" написать минимально рабочий кусочек разметки и стилей, убедившись что он работает (что отображается нормально, пусть и без желаемого выравнивания картинок). Сами картинки можно взять с https://picsum.photos например.

Comment: @humster_spb, сделал то, что Вы просили

Comment: @yar85, спасибо, все сделал по инструкции и все получилось отлично

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, какой результат Вам нужен, то `object-fit` вполне справляется с этой задачей. Главное - задать изображениям явные размеры: не `max-width`, а именно `width: 100%` и `height: 50%` (ну, или ту высоту, которая Вам необходима). И `display: block` для того, чтобы убрать отступы, характерные для inline-элементов:

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.gallery {
    display: flex;
}

.gallery__col {
    width: 25%;
}

.gallery__img {
    display: block;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="section__header">
            <h3 class="section__title">Галлерея</h3>
            <p class="section__text">Эстетика интерьера и кофе</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery__col">
            <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/400/600">
            <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/600/400">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery__col">
            <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/300">
            <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/700/500">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery__col">
            <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300">
            <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/350/300">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery__col">
            <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/800/500">
            <img class="gallery__img" src="https://picsum.photos/400/400">
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: да, точно, я просто не правильно использовал height, большое спасибо!